# Where does this unit vector come from?

Tags: mathematical-physics, vectors

Although this is a physics problem, the problem is in regard to vectors.

There is the relevant reference to this image here:[image: pole and forces]

What I need to find is the unit vector of force ***$F_1$***. The book gives it as the following: $$u_{F_1} = sin 35° cos 20° i - sin 35° sin 20° j + cos 35° k
$$ I would like to know *where* this set of cosines/sines comes from, and how do I get it? Where does the $sin 35° cos 20° i$ come from? Shouldn't it be (in my understanding of the picture) $cos 20° i$? (Same question for the j and k unit's as well) On top of the that, is this a general form equation? How do I know which angles to pick?

Comment: google for spherical polar coordinates

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, I understand what spherical coordinates are... but why on earth are those forms being used here? Heck, it doesn't even seem to me to have a sphere anywhere involved.

Comment: given that you know the magnitude of vector and two angles (azimuthal and polar), you can decompose the vector into x, y and z components ... which is what you get as above.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I think I understand, but if you don't mind, could you please explain how, especially in the i and j, the 35 is coming from?

Comment: The $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ unit vectors are a basis for the $x-y$ plane. If you consider the projection of $F_1$ down onto this plane (imagine the shadow being cast by the point at the end of $F_1$), then it should be clear that it is a function of $\sin 35^{\circ}$, since $F_1$ is the hypotenuse of the triangle formed along the direction of $F_1$ projected onto the $x-y$ plane, and $\sin 35^{\circ}$ is the "opposite" of that triangle.

Comment: There is a sphere here :-) The reason is that unit vectors are vectors of length 1, i.e. if you place the vector's tail at the origin its head lies on the unit sphere. So, in disguise, your question is "where does the vector $F_1$ meet a unit sphere?"

Comment: @Arkamis, if it is a shadow, what is the need for the 35? Wouldn't it be on the x,y plane? It still seems to me it would be cos 20 to find, in case of the i unit vector.

Comment: scroll this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Geographic_coordinates) a bit upwards ... use $r=1$ and as for $y$ note the direction.

Comment: @Link Lay a stick down on the floor. Step on one end of the stick. Lift the other end until it makes a 35-degree angle with your leg. Look at where the tip of the stick is in relation to the floor.

Comment: @Arkamis... I just did that.. the tip of the stick is above the floor?

Comment: also check this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/13R5J.png

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Thank you sooo much! That makes a ton of sense now.

Comment: @Link Draw a line straight down from the tip of the stick. Where is it?

Comment: @Arkamis, it is... right below the tip, but more towards my foot than having the stick on the floor?

Comment: Yes. So, that is a different coordinate. That coordinate is based completely on the size of the stick, it's orientation with respect to the floor, and the angle it makes with your leg. That's where the $\sin 35^\circ$ comes from -- the angle it makes with your leg.

Comment: @Arkamis, I see now. Thank you.